# IOException from Serilog with SEQ? How to troubleshoot and solve?

Tags: serilog, ioexception, seq

I have a simple Windows Service with the following features :

- .Net 6.0
- RabbitMQ
- Serilog
- Serilog Seq, email, console, MSSql, Configuration...
- Dependency Injection (Microsoft)
- EntityFramework
- HostBuilder

The service starts up fine MQ queues are created and log data is coming in to both console and Seq. A couple of seconds after startup(while application waiting on MQ messages) an IOException is thrown which is posted to both console and Seq, this is how the console looks like :

```sh
    [17:31:25.720 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.SharedObjectService.Program "Myapp.Cloud.SharedObjectService" microservice starting up.
    
    [17:31:25.790 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.SharedObjectService.Program Database: Data Source=Uranus;Initial Catalog=MyappCloudDev;User ID=sa;Password=jaffa
    
    [17:31:26.689 [Information]  "Myapp.Cloud.SharedObjectService" all built.
    
    [17:31:26.982 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.MQ.MQCloudProducer MQCloudProducer.Producer is connecting to MQ service "Myapp.Cloud.MQ" at "localhost"
    
    [17:31:26.982 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.MQ.MQCloudConsumer MQCloudConsumer.Connecting to MQ service "Myapp.Cloud.MQ" at "localhost" with user """" and DestinationCode "SharedObjectService"
    
    [17:31:27.143 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.MQ.MQCloudProducer Producer connected to MQ service "Myapp.Cloud.MQ".
    
    [17:31:27.144 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.MQ.MQCloudConsumer MQCloudConsumer.Connecting to MQ service "Myapp.Cloud.MQ" at "localhost" with user """" and DestinationCode "SharedObjectService"
    
    [17:31:27.144 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.SharedObjectService.BusinessLogicLayer.SharedObjectService "SharedObject" microservice started.
    
    [17:31:36.504 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.MQ.MQCloudConsumer MQCloudConsumer.Connected to MQ service queue "Myapp.Cloud.MQ":"SendSharedObject" at "localhost".
    
    [17:31:36.504 [Information] Myapp.Cloud.MQ.MQCloudConsumer MQCloudConsumer.Connected to MQ service queue "Myapp.Cloud.MQ":"OutputResponse" at "localhost".
    
    FirstChanceException : System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
     ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.CreateException(SocketError error, Boolean forAsyncThrow)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ReceiveAsync(Socket socket, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ReceiveAsync(Memory`1 buffer, SocketFlags socketFlags, Boolean fromNetworkStream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<CheckUsabilityOnScavenge>g__ReadAheadWithZeroByteReadAsync|44_0()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<CheckUsabilityOnScavenge>g__ReadAheadWithZeroByteReadAsync|44_0()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.CheckUsabilityOnScavenge()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<CleanCacheAndDisposeIfUnused>g__IsUsableConnection|115_2(HttpConnectionBase connection, Int64 nowTicks, TimeSpan pooledConnectionLifetime, TimeSpan pooledConnectionIdleTimeout)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<CleanCacheAndDisposeIfUnused>g__ScavengeConnectionList|115_1[T](List`1 list, List`1& toDispose, Int64 nowTicks, TimeSpan pooledConnectionLifetime, TimeSpan pooledConnectionIdleTimeout)
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CleanCacheAndDisposeIfUnused()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager.RemoveStalePools()
       at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPoolManager.<>c.<.ctor>b__11_0(Object s)
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.CallCallback(Boolean isThreadPool)
       at System.Threading.TimerQueueTimer.Fire(Boolean isThreadPool)
       at System.Threading.TimerQueue.FireNextTimers()
       at System.Threading.TimerQueue.AppDomainTimerCallback(Int32 id)
       at System.Threading.UnmanagedThreadPoolWorkItem.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
       at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
       at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
       at System.Threading.Thread.StartCallback()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
    
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
    FirstChanceException : System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
     ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Its only the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException` that fetch this exception. Break on all errors or stepping do not show exception or where it occurs? The Exception do only have a system stacktrace, nothing related ty the project code.

If I remove the Seq part of the appsettings file the problem is gone.

The Serilog part of appsettings.json look like this :

```json
    "serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "Serilog.Sinks.Email" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
          "Default": "Information",
          "Override": {
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "System": "Warning"
          }
        },
        "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId" ],
        "WriteTo": [
          {
            "Name": "Console",
            "Args": {
              "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {SourceContext} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
              "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
              "path": "/Logs/log.txt",
              "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
              "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
              "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000000,
              "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
              "shared": "true",
              "flushToDiskInterval": 3
            }
    
          },
          {
            "Name": "Seq",
            "Args": {
              "serverUrl": "http://localhost:8081/"
            }
          },
          {
            "Name": "MSSqlServer",
            "Args": {
              "connectionString": "Data Source=x;Initial Catalog=MyAppClouddev;User ID=x;Password=x",
              "tableName": "Logs",
              "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Fatal"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Serilog are called like this(Structured logging) :

```
_logger.LogInformation("OutputResponse received {@message}, {@messageGuid}, {@messageChainGuid}", args.Data, args.Data.MessageGuid, args.Data.MessageChainGuid);
```

Some times it might not just be string values that are logged but whole objects.

How do you troubleshoot this?

EDIT : When turning off "just my code" I can see that the exception is thrown from within a Microsoft library and I can see that the URL(with port) is the same as the SEQ service got(serverURL) so that Is why I Think the problem are due to this sink. And if I remove the Seq part of the configuration I do not get any exceptions. The regular logging to console are working just fine.

Comment: It's unusual to have Seq running on port 8081 - could you have the port number in the Seq URL wrong here?

Comment: @NicholasBlumhardt, yes, Im not sure why it ended up at port 8081, suppose I could change it. But the local SEQ webpage works fine and it does get more or less all the log rows from my service. What port should I place the service at? And could there be a problem sending some kind of data? In some cases whole objects are sent but I suppose that they will be translated to regular string text with JSON or likewise?

Comment: I don't understand what this issue has to do with Serilog and Seq. You have an error coming from your app, which happens to get logged via Serilog, and since you have the Seq sink set up, you see it there. Is there anything specific that leads you to believe that Seq is actually related to your exception?

Comment: @mason pleas see my EDIT.

Comment: Did you [try enabling the self-log](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Debugging-and-Diagnostics) in Serilog? Do you ever log very large objects?

Comment: So far I haven´t been able to activate selflog, I have tried to solve it for a couple of days so no there is a new post about it here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71806534/why-does-not-serilog-selflog-work-in-this-simple-windows-service

I use structure logging and from time there is more complex objects that are logged. When this is done the @ is used in front of the keyword to instruct to translate to JSON.

Comment: Regardless, I don't think your problem is actually with Serilog or Seq. Perhaps something else is accidentally getting configured to use the same port that you've got Seq listening on. You should start removing components from your app until the problem goes away. That will help you narrow down what component is responsible. Probably something with an internal timer and/or HttpClient usage. Another option would be to use a tool like Wireshark to see what's sending packets to that port. The contents of those packets may give a clue as to what's sending them.