# Why does not Serilog selflog work in this simple windows service?

Tags: c#, logging, serilog, diagnostics

I am unable to get Serilog selflog working in my .NET Core 6.0 C# Windows Service. This is how the Main looks like :

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Seri-serlflog : {msg}"));

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().DefaultLoggerSetup<Program>();
            var serviceName = "MyService";

            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var appSettings = configurationBuilder.Get<AppSettings>();

            try
            {
                Log.Information("{@serviceName} microservice starting up.", serviceName);
                
                var built = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration))
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        services
                            .AddHostedService<MyApp.Cloud.MyService.BusinessLogicLayer.MyService>()
                            .Configure<MySettings>(configurationBuilder.GetSection("MQSettings"))
                            .AddAutoMapper(typeof(ConnectorToCloudTreatment))
                            .AddTransi...
                    }).Build();
                Log.Information("{@serviceName} all built.", serviceName);
                built.Run();
                Log.Information("{@serviceName} microservice closing down.", serviceName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Unhanled exception in {@serviceName}.", serviceName);
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.Information("{@serviceName} Cleaning up.", serviceName);
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
                Log.Information("{@serviceName} Application Exit.", serviceName);
            }
        }
    }
```

The serilog part of application.json looks like this :

```
  "serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer", "Serilog.Sinks.Email" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Console",
        "Args": {
          "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {SourceContext} {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
          "theme": "Serilog.Sinks.SystemConsole.Themes.AnsiConsoleTheme::Code, Serilog.Sinks.Console"
        }
      },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "/Logs/logs.txt",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} {SourceContext} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine:1}{Exception:1}",
          "formatter": "Serilog.Formatting.Json.JsonFormatter, Serilog",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
          "shared": "true",
          "flushToDiskInterval": 3
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I do a lot of logging in this application and it works fine but there is a couple of problems and to find why I need to use the selflog but I do not get any information at all to the output > debug?

Edit : Seems like this may have something to do with the injection. In program.cs I use the static Log but in all other classes I use injected typed loggers. But regardless I should get a couple of $"Seri-serlflog : {msg}" rows in the output?

Comment: If you write a message to the self-log, do you see it in the debug output?
`Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.WriteLine("Test");`

Comment: I tried placing your example in both main method above and in a class that is injected and both worked fine.

Comment: In that case, I would try forcing something that definitely uses the self-logging internally.
The [MessageTemplate](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/blob/2aabe64a323ff449a2a483968e03d57e4d0bb19d/src/Serilog/Events/MessageTemplate.cs#L58) uses the self-log if it encounters a bad message template. You could try intentionally supplying a bad template, and verifying that way.

Comment: Placing this : Log.Information("{sName} started.", "Service1", "test"); just after var serviceName the console writes a proper line without "test". Serilog selflog do however print to Ouput : "...property count do not match...". But if i place the same Log.Information in a contructor of a injected class I get e hard Exception(ArgumentNullException). This generates a lot of exception text in output but there is also a selflog entry about "Exception while emitting periodic batch...request canceled" witch is probably a side effect of the hard exception.

Comment: As far as the self-log is concerned, this sounds like it is working as expected. Regarding the ArgumentNullException, I'd need to see more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get debug level logging, you'll have to loosen your log level:

```
"MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Debug",
        "System": "Debug"
      }
```

Comment: Thanks but that did not help, still no output at all from the selflog. Will setting the Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable enable selflog for all instances? Even injected?